# Why normally ES6 are supported or mentioned?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was reading the official Nuxt.js guide, but it says it is only supporting ES6/ES7.

In normal cases, the newest version of ES8 or ES9, they are ignored or not supported yet?

Is there any reason that ES6 is used as a term to mention the newest Javascript version than latest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newser ES standards don't need to be supported by these libraries. You can normally provide support for later standards and experimental features by babel.